# How can I access UDP ports using a web application on the client PC?

Tags: flash, web-applications, udp

One of the thing that current Windows application does is that it writes out information to a hardware device via a UDP message. We are considering porting the application to web-based.

I checked Silverlight, and that doesn't allow UDP. We don't want to use ActiveX or Java Applets.

What are the other options?

Thanks.

**Update** - does anyone know if I can use Flash to do this?

Comment: Flash only supports TCP sockets, unfortunately.

Comment: I was afraid of that... well, looks like a change in strategy is required.

Answer (score 1):

You could always have a middleman - have some software running, listening for tcp connections that forwards the data to the udp client.

Other than that, you can only use TCP with pretty much any browser-based socket technology.

Comment: One of the reasons why we are moving to web is because the users don't want to install anything on their computer. So, a middleman is not an option.

Comment: no no..I meant you have the middleman hosted on your server. The client connects to the TCp middleman.

Comment: Yes, but in that case I am not necessarily going to be able to access the device which is hosted on the client's local LAN from my server... Ideally, the client needs to connect directly to the target.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken, you've eliminated all your options for something like that.

There's not going to be a way for a page on a client browser to write to a UDP stream on that client machine without some form of thick client.

(I'm assuming you're talking about a device attached to the client PC rather than the Web Server)

Comment: Yes, a device either directly attached to the client PC, or accessible through the local LAN of the client PC.

And about your response, I was afraid of that.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a "web-technology-based" solution outside of the browser, from v2.0 AIR supports [UDP sockets](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/DatagramSocket.html?allClasses=1). Which is almost like Flash supporting them, except different. (I know this isn't quite what you asked, but since plugins normally run their networking stack through the browser I think it's as close as you can get..)